# Is there any way to make my C# XMLManager work?

Tags: c#, xml

so I'm a total noob to C# is there any way to make this work?
It would also be a great help if someone could explain why my system doesn't work, and why another version would.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class XMLManager
{
    private XmlTextReader reader;
    private XmlDocument document;
    private XmlNodeList nodeList;

    public void OpenFile(string file)
    {
        try
        {
            reader = new XmlTextReader(file);
            reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
            reader.MoveToContent();
            document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(reader);
            nodeList = document.SelectNodes(@"Settings/Settings");
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
        }
    }

    public void CloseFile()
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
            reader.Close();
            reader = null;
        }
        document = null;
        nodeList = null;
    }

    public string Get(string attrib)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            reader.MoveToAttribute(i);
            if (reader.Name == attrib)
            {
                return reader.Value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Edit: Sorry for my bad formatting, this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: how is someone supposed to tell you why your system does not work.. also what does `does not work mean???` you should also use the debugger and step through your code.. if it's on your machine how come you can't debug it..? furthermore .. this is not a code factory / testing site.. once again..`Debugger` is your friend if you know how to use it properly

Comment: Define "work"; what is happening that you don't expect, or what is not happening that you do expect?

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?  You say *my system doesn't work* but don't describe the problem.  Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It's good that you show the code that doesn't work -- now, tell us what it's doing wrong, including a sample of the XML that causes problems.

Comment: What is the question?  What doesn't work?

Comment: I can see one thing you are doing wrong -- you are catching and ignoring `FileNotFoundException`.  If your file is missing your code will silently fail with no notification.

Comment: The reader doesnot have the context of the selected nodes at the point of searching for the attributes. It is the reason the code is failing right now. But besides that, there are many other errors starting with ignoring the file not found exception, using a reader for an xml file just to load it into an XmlDocument, and looking for the demanded attribute in all matching Settings/Settings nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making multiple mistakes here.

First of all, you don't need a reader to read xml content into an XmlDocument.

Second, while trying to get the attributes, you are trying to proceed to the attributes using the reader which is obviously not having the context of the selected nodes.

Here is your updated XmlManager, but I have to note, there is a logical error too, which is, when the GetAttribute is invoked, you are searching all the Settings/Settings nodes and if find the attribute in any of them, return it. If the xml file contains only one Settings/Settings node, `SelectSingleNode` is better. I assume the following format:

```
  <Settings>
    <Settings attr1="attr1val" attr2="attr2val" />
  </Settings>
```

Note: I also removed CloseFile method because it is no longer required.

```
public class XMLManager
{
    private XmlDocument document;
    private XmlNodeList nodeList;

    public void OpenFile(string file)
    {
        document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(file);
        nodeList = document.SelectNodes(@"Settings/Settings");
    }

    public string Get(string attrib)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nodeList[i].Attributes[attrib] != null)
            {
                return nodeList[i].Attributes[attrib].Value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation and the fixed code, helped me understand 'System.Xml' a lot better in general. Also `SelectSingleNode` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I could get it working, works great. Thanks!

Comment: tested before posted :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Overall, you're doing way too much work.

If you have XML in a file, load it directly into an XML (DOM) object using XmlDocument.Load( strFileName );

To iterate all nodes matching an XPath query, see how I run through them.

```
    try {
        string strFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\data.xml");
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load( strFileName );
        foreach (XmlElement ndRow in xml.SelectNodes("//row")) {
            string strTemp = ndRow.GetAttribute("foo");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```